# Парсинг динамического содержимого сайта нестандартными методами

Tags: python, ajax, парсер

Добрый день, уважаемые пользователи. Мой вопрос таков: есть сайт http://novostroykirf.ru/1/#!devsearch;page=1. Мне следует слить табличку с этой первой страницы размером 20*4. Вопрос в том, что обычные методы типа посмотреть запрос и сформировать такой же через Firebug или же связка Selenium+PhantomJS не работает. Сделать это надо на Python, но что-то я сел капитально и даже не представляю, чего дальше делать

Comment: Пользовательские скрипты пробовали?

Comment: Пользовательские скрипты? А это что такое? Расскажете, если можно? Я javascript не знаю от слова совсем

Comment: Отличие Ghost от Beautiful Soup и Scrapy в том, что у него под капотом целый браузер, которой может js скрипты выполнять. Таким образом нужно только взять данные в нужный момент. По идее все что в обычном браузере вы видите, должно быть доступно и через Ghost.

Comment: Я не умею писать на js. Без него можно как-то это сделать? Мне задание поставили вообще на R написать, но он не особо-то подходит, потому вожусь с Python

Comment: То что у Ghost браузер со скриптами, это к тому, что он может также страницу видеть как и вы в обычном браузере. Для этого знаний js не требуется. Но в любом случае надо хотя бы про DOM иметь представление, из которого вы будете данные питоном выковыривать.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian под капотом Ghost, насколько я знаю,  PhantomJS. Да и под названием тоже.

Comment: @D-side все верно, наверное надо было все таки использовать другое слово вместо "браузер", чтобы показать, что там не просто парсер html. Вебкит например.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian просто, хм, Селениум с Фантомом, если верить автору, не осилили :)

Comment: @D-side ну он в js не силен, трудно наверное с PhantomJS было.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian не с Selenium :)

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужны не все данные с этого сайта, а только одна страница, то скопируйте просто element таблицы в текстовый документ (консоль разработчика в Chrome) и далее разбирайте его средствами Python (библиотека lxml).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А где вы нашли table? У меня его нет

Comment: Хотя мне все равно надо именно на Питоне, а не через консоль. Хотя изначально вообще на R заставляли

Comment: Я и предлагаю сделать на Python, только вам нужно скопировать HTML код этой таблицы через консоль и сохранить в файл. Далее работайте с этим файлом на Python.

Comment: Так я и спрашиваю, где вы эту таблицу нашли? У меня ее вроде как нет. Или я ее в упор не вижу, потому что глаз замылился

Comment: Данные таблицы загружаются динамически. Поэтому, вам нужно дождаться загрузки данных и далее через консоль разработчика скопировать html код; Консоль доступна по умолчанию в браузере Chrome. Что бы найти нужный элемент, нажмите правой кнопкой на заголовке таблицы и выберите в меню - просмотреть код.

Comment: А может задержку в PhantomJS выставить? Это не поможет? Ну типа динамика прогрузится, потом мы ее сольем и дальше lxml пойдет работать?

Answer (score 0):

В общем, ларчик-то просто открывался. Надо было поставить десятисекундную задержку, чтоб запрос отработал и динамическое содержимое прогрузилось. Так что связка Selenium+PhantomJS вполне жизнеспособна